# Requirements for flag to close option to appear?

Tags: support, flags

The [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) says that the "Duplicate question" and "Off topic" flag to close reasons only appear once you have 50 reputation, which suggests to me that the other close reasons (eg Too broad) should be available at 15 reputation, when the ability to flag kicks in.

However, when I click to flag a question I only ever get the options

- Spam
- Offensive etc
- Very low quality
- other (needs moderator attention)

with no close option. Am I misreading the help page? Is there some other requirement that needs to be met for the Flag to close option to appear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, that was a mistake; *none* of those options show up. Partially because some of them generate comments (duplicate), mostly because we just don't need folks who haven't done much of anything here trying to get stuff closed.

I've taken the liberty of adding asterisks to *all* of the lines involving close reasons. Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

As of October 12th, 2016 all flags options, including flagging to close, are available once you reach 15 reputation. The rationale is in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285766/158100) from [bluefeet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/164200/bluefeet) and copied here verbatim:

> As of this morning, we've loosened some of the restrictions for users with flag privileges but not enough rep to comment. This change specifically targets users with rep >= 15 and < 50.
>
> Users falling in this range of reputation will now be able to flag posts as "should be closed" on the flagging dialog; this includes duplicates. Previously, this was restricted because users did not have the ability to comment. We've have made it possible for users to create the auto-comment, if the flagging option creates one (i.e. duplicates), but since the user does not have the ability to comment they will not be able to edit the comment until they've gained that privilege.
>
> This should alleviate some of the confusion for lower rep users flagging things for moderator attention, when they should use standard flag/close options.

It worked as advertised after [this bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336903) was fixed.