# Requirement for flag duplicate to appear

Tags: support, flags

My question is very similar to an earlier question about [requirement for the flag to close option is supposed to appear](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260914/requirements-for-flag-to-close-option-to-appear).

The answer to that earlier question (which is about why certain flag-to-close options should appear when reputation reaches 15) seems to imply that the [help page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260914/requirements-for-flag-to-close-option-to-appear) will be edited to reflect that those item should appear when reputation reaches 50 instead.

However, my reputation is currently above 50 but when I click on flag, I don't have those options too. Particularly I was trying to flag a question as duplicate.

[image]

So is there another requirement for flag duplicate to appear which is not documented yet in the help page?

Comment: Ah I just discovered that it has been closed as duplicate. So possibly in the time I spent reading, researching, and deciding to flag, enough people has already acted on it and closed the question, just that I haven't refreshed my screen to see it happen ...

Answer (score 3):

Not all options will be available when flagging if the question has been closed or deleted.

This is especially common when handling duplicates, as during the time that you are searching for the duplicate, others may have already flagged it. Duplicate questions in common tags are likely to be closed very quickly, and [often by a gold hammer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254589/359284), so you will likely see this in the future.

The same applies to answers which have been deleted, where the flagging dialog will suddenly only show the "Other" option.