# Is there a way to know if my question and answer is flagged when I have low reputation?

Tags: support, flags, duplicate-questions, reputation

Sometimes my questions and answers are flagged by other users that it is duplicate or not useful, even if it's not real duplicate.

If I see that my question or answer is flagged, I can change it in detail so that it cannot be served as duplicate. But I cannot see if it has been flagged. Is this a reputation problem?

If I have more reputation, can I see if my question is flagged? How much reputation do users need to see flagged questions and answers?

Some people don't make comments and flag my posts anyway.

Comment: If a question is flagged as duplicate, an auto generated comment ("possible duplicate of") is generated. Otherwise it's up to the others to tell you what is wrong with your post.

Comment: This ^ and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes)

Comment: you cant see (non duplicate) flags on your post irrespective of your rep

Comment: you can post links to questions that are similar to your question but did not solve your problem and say "I looked at this and this answer, but it did not solve my problem". I think that would discourage people from quickly looking some answers up and flagging. That also shows you did some research before posting.

Answer (score 11):

As [Alon Eitan indicates](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354686/is-there-a-way-to-know-if-my-question-and-answer-is-flagged-when-i-have-low-repu/354687?noredirect=1#comment501895_354686), once you gain [250 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes), you'll be able to see close *votes* on your own questions. Not close flags, but those only serve to send the question to the [Close Vote review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close) where actual close votes can be cast.

Other than that, you can see the comment that is automatically generated when somebody flags/votes-to-close a question as a duplicate (as [mentioned by Walfrat](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354686/is-there-a-way-to-know-if-my-question-and-answer-is-flagged-when-i-have-low-repu#comment501893_354686)), or if somebody votes to close your question with a custom off-topic reason. Those comments are visible to everybody.

You can't see flags on answers (unless you are a ♦ moderator), but the [Low Quality Posts review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts) generates some standard comments which indicate your answer is being investigated. An example of such a comment:

> While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Such a comment will finish with a 'From Review' link which leads you to the review item.

Comment: I couldn't remember, and couldn't find here on Meta, confirmation about whether *flagging* leaves the "possible duplicate" comment. Does it, or is that only for those with close vote privileges?

Comment: @CodyGray from my personal experience (on other sites), flagging as duplicate leaves the same comment as voting to close.

Comment: @Cody it does. Previously you had to have 50 rep to flag as duplicate (but 15+ for anything else) purely because it left an automatic comment and comments were prohibited from users with < 50 on posts they didn't own. Some tweaking was done to allow that comment to be posted and users able to use that flag reason.

Comment: @JonClements wasn't there a case where some <50 rep used that loophole to leave comment on a question by first cv-ing as dupe and then editing the possible dupe comment? Or did we only fantasize about that option?

Comment: @rene https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/336698/4751173 Seems to have been thought of *before* it went live.

Comment: @rene no - that was catered for - but a little too well - whereby users couldn't delete/edit comments they should have been able to previously (on their own Qs or answers to their own Qs)

Comment: @Glorfindel please offer links to answers of users who are credible ... pffffff ....

Comment: @rene I'll keep it in mind for the next time.

Comment: And the bug report for that weird scenario is [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336903/changes-to-allow-15-rep-dupe-flagging-might-be-preventing-50-rep-users-to-genu)

Comment: "once you gain 250 reputation, you'll be able to see close votes on your own questions". Is it real?? Most close-votes target posts from low-rep users. If they don't see close-votes, they don't have a chance to fix problems with their Q before it gets closed

Comment: @ASh yes, I must say I haven't understood the philosophy behind that either.